# Systemd service - Python script inside Screen on boot

Tags: python, linux, systemd, gnu-screen

Im currently running a python script inside a Screen session through this script in rc.local:

```
screen -L -dmS pi python /home/pi/truck/main2.py &
```

But I would like it to run through systemd so I can restart it if the Python script crashes.

I tried creating a service in /systemd/system/myscript.service

```
[Unit]
Description=myscript
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -L -dmS pi  python /home/pi/truck/main2.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it wont run my script inside the Screen session?

If I get a list of running screens it shows that the screen session "pi" is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Try with explicit paths such as ...

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/screen -L -dmS pi  /usr/bin/python /home/pi/truck/main2.py'
```

Ordinarily, you can debug these by iterations of the call.
For example, in *terminal* try (and proceed with each success)

1. `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/truck/main2.py`
2. `/usr/bin/screen -L -dmS pi  /usr/bin/python /home/pi/truck/main2.py`
3. `/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/screen -L -dmS pi  /usr/bin/python /home/pi/truck/main2.py'`

If **#3** works as desired then you copy it into the service file. At the end of the day, that's really all `systemd` is doing in this case. If you were trying to run the script as a different user, you'd use something like `su - pi` to test and use `User=pi` in the service file if you are debugging as *root*.